# table headings spread over two lines to make table shorter

Tags: tables, columns, width

My table is written with...

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx} {\linewidth}{ll>{\raggedright}Xr}
```

[image: table]

But I want to spread the text in the first two columns, e.g. preparatory work and omitting a step, over two lines because I want to first two columns to reduce in width and the third to increase in width. I tried with `\multicolumn{1}{m{2cm}` but it does not work.

Is there a simple better way? (Explain for people who can't really code please)

Comment: What about the contents of the other rows? Will there be other terms in the first column in which you want to introduce a linebreak or is "preparatory work"  the only example that needs to be split over two lines?

Comment: Preparatory / work is the only one from the first column. From the second column there are two phrases: Adding / information and Organising / Information that I want to separate in two lines. This should make my third column wider (hopefully)

Comment: See updated answer, example 2

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the two first columns to paragraph columns, either using `p{}, or and X-column (you have to change to tabularx or xltabular).

If you use tabularx, you can set the first two columns as fixed width `p` columns, and the third as an `X`-column that use rest of the available space between the margins. See example 2, which I will provide in a minute or two.

if you need a multi page tabular, please indicate that, and I will update the code. It is also possible to set the columns ragged right.

**Example 1 - tabular**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}p{2cm}p{2cm}p{5cm}@{}}
 \toprule
 \bfseries Theme & \bfseries Code & \bfseries Description\\
 \midrule
  Preparatory Work & Omitting a step & Lot of interesting text that fills up lots of lines. Even more lines than you can think of if you continue to write nonsense!\\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**Example 2 - tabularx**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{2cm}p{2cm}X@{}}
 \toprule
 \bfseries Theme & \bfseries Code & \bfseries Description\\
 \midrule
  Preparatory Work & Omitting a step & Lot of interesting text that fills up lots of lines. Even more lines than you can think of if you continue to write nonsense! As you see, column three expands to take the rest of the line width.\\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a limited number of cases in which you want to add a linebreak inside of a table cell, you could use the `makecell` package for that. If there are more occurrences in a table (or more specifie: in a certain column), you definitely should have a look at the `p` type column, that [Sveinung mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/545709/134144).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ll>{\raggedright}Xr}
    \toprule
\textbf{Label 1}& \textbf{Label 2}&\textbf{Label 3}& $N$\\
\midrule
\makecell[lt]{preparatory\\ work} &\makecell[lt]{Adding\\ information}&
Description on several lines. Description on several lines.
Description on several lines. Description on several lines.
& 2
\\
 &\makecell[lt]{organizing\\ information}&
New Description on several lines. Description on several lines.
Description on several lines. Description on several lines.
& 3
\\
word &short term&
Description on several lines. Description on several lines.
Description on several lines. Description on several lines.
& 2
\\
\bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked! Amazing, thank you :)